# Show that $x^3 + 3x^2 + 9x + 3$ and $x^3 + 3x^2 + 3x − 4$ are irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

I need to show, as stated in the title, that $x^3 + 3x^2 + 9x + 3$ and  $x^3 + 3x^2 + 3x − 4$ are irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

I know that in **case of second polynomial**, if $f(x-1) = x^3 - 5$ which is irreducible, but i dont know how to form a solution from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First** can be proved using **Eisenstein's Criteria**

**Second**  You've already evaluated $f(x-1)$ correctly and since $f(x-1)$ is irreducible. So will be the case with $f(x)$. **(why?)**

Comment: Not sure how i missed Eisenstein's Criteria.

Comment: For the second, if a is a root for $f(x-1)$ <=> a+1 is a root for $f(x)$ ?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right.